# javascript object store

Tags: javascript

Does there exist a micro-framework for use in browser (IE-support is optional) which provides a convenient document store functionality that meets the requirements below :

1. It should support getters and setters that can handle nested objects.
2. It should be observable - updating an object, adding additonal attributes to objects can be watched for change.
3. Efficient filtering / querying functionality.

It would be nice if the document store can be persisted using IndexDB but persistence is not a strict requirement.

Comment: [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) is an option.

Comment: Backbone models/collections don't support observing nested object attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option I have found so far is Nathan Sobo's [Monarch](https://github.com/nathansobo/monarch).

Quoting the description :

> Monarch is a relational modeling framework for client-centric web applications. It's superficially similar to Backbone.js, but it uses the relational algebra as a declarative, compositional language for querying data and subscribing to events. Monarch is written in CoffeeScript, but can also be used from JavaScript.

While it supports requirements 2,3 out of the box, 1 can be simulated through standard relations between tables. If the backend database is relational, then it is trivially easy to replicate the same structure (along with the associated table relationships) on the client.

If relations between tables are not a requirement, then [TaffyDB](http://www.taffydb.com/) by [Ian Smith](https://twitter.com/biastoact) also seems to be a good option, though I haven't looked through it thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

there are many many options like: backbone.js, ember.js, todo.js, ect. I use mostly backbone and ember.

Comment: I am not fully informed about Ember, But Backbone models/collections don't support observing nested object attributes.